# Сделать шифр невидимым

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Eсть шифр Бэкона, надо исправить чтоб шифр стал невидимый, A-пробел B-табуляция**

**Код:**

```
message=str(input("Введите сообщение:"))

keys = {'A':'aaaaa', 'B':'aaaab', 'C':'aaaba', 'D':'aaabb',
        'E':'aabaa',  'F':'aabab', 'G':'aabba', 'H':'aabbb',
        'I':'abaaa', 'J':'abaab','K':'ababa', 'L':'ababb',
        'M':'abbaa', 'N':'abbab', 'O':'abbba','P':'abbbb',
        'Q':'baaaa', 'R':'baaab', 'S':'baaba', 'T':'baabb' ,
        'U':'babaa', 'V':'babab', 'W':'babba', 'X':'babbb',
        'Y':'bbaaa', 'Z':'bbaab', ' ':'bbaba'}

encrypt = ""
for i in message:#перебираем по символу сообщение
     for j in keys:#перебираем кейс
         if i == j:
            encrypt+=keys[i]
print(encrypt)

decrypt = "" ; k = "" # k-счётчик
for i in encrypt: #перебираем по encrypt
    k += i
    if len(k) == 5:
        for j in keys:#перебираем кейс
            if k == keys[j]:
                decrypt += j
                k = ""#обнуление
print(decrypt)
```

Comment: a и b замените на пробелы и табуляции и все. в чем конкретно проблема ?

Comment: вы можете поменять в программе

Comment: он не корректно выводит данные

Answer (score 0):

Заменяем `a` на  , `b` на `\t`, можно это сделать автоматически:

```
keys = {k:v.replace('a',' ').replace('b','\t') for k,v in keys.items()}
print(keys)
```

Вывод:

```
{'A': '     ', 'B': '    \t', 'C': '   \t ', 'D': '   \t\t', 'E': '  \t  ', 'F': '  \t \t', 'G': '  \t\t ', 'H': '  \t\t\t', 'I': ' \t   ', 'J': ' \t  \t', 'K': ' \t \t ', 'L': ' \t \t\t', 'M': ' \t\t  ', 'N': ' \t\t \t', 'O': ' \t\t\t ', 'P': ' \t\t\t\t', 'Q': '\t    ', 'R': '\t   \t', 'S': '\t  \t ', 'T': '\t  \t\t', 'U': '\t \t  ', 'V': '\t \t \t', 'W': '\t \t\t ', 'X': '\t \t\t\t', 'Y': '\t\t   ', 'Z': '\t\t  \t', ' ': '\t\t \t '}
```

Comment: А куда конкретно это вставить можете вставить это в мою программу и скинуть пожалуйста

Comment: `keys = {'A': '     ', 'B': '    \t', 'C': '   \t ', 'D': '   \t\t', 'E': '  \t  ', 'F': '  \t \t', 'G': '  \t\t ', 'H': '  \t\t\t', 'I': ' \t   ', 'J': ' \t  \t', 'K': ' \t \t ', 'L': ' \t \t\t', 'M': ' \t\t  ', 'N': ' \t\t \t', 'O': ' \t\t\t ', 'P': ' \t\t\t\t', 'Q': '\t    ', 'R': '\t   \t', 'S': '\t  \t ', 'T': '\t  \t\t', 'U': '\t \t  ', 'V': '\t \t \t', 'W': '\t \t\t ', 'X': '\t \t\t\t', 'Y': '\t\t   ', 'Z': '\t\t  \t', ' ': '\t\t \t '}`

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ